# Using REST to send data through Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How do I send an XML or JSON format file into Apache Kafka by hitting a REST API ?

Comment: Is this already setup (in which case, what exactly are you asking?), or are you asking how to set this up? (and define "through", are you passing it to a service or another server?)

Comment: I am not asking about setup, I just want to know how to send the data by hitting REST API in producer and send that to consumer side.

Comment: Consider editing your question to say "send data" not "send date" so it is more clear what you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to publish to Kafka via the open source Confluent Kafka REST Proxy (see 
http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html)

The same REST Proxy also supports consuming from Kafka via HTTP(S) as well as producing.

Comment: Please share the command to send XML file from producer to consumer in windows.

Comment: The Kafka REST API is documented here http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#produce-and-consume-binary-messages

Comment: I have already read this document, I want to send XML file in windows system and this document covers about Unix commands

Comment: What program are you using on windows for REST? You can install curl for windows or use another tool. If you will be working a lot with REST it would be useful to learn to use curl since most example use this tool.